# How to make a comparison of part of an array with one value

Tags: python, arrays, comparison

```
if x[3] > y and x[4] > y and x[5] > y and x[6] > y and x[7] > y and x[8] > y:
           ...
```

Do U have a more elegant method to compare it? actually, I have to compare one value with 30 values in the array, do U know a better way to write it?

Comment: [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) is your friend. `any(ex<=y for ex in x[3:9])` or [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) for all tests being true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `all` function:

```
if all(val > y for val in x[3:9]):
   # your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use all function like:
if all(val > y for val in x[3:9]):

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this.

Use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a slice of your list:

```
 if any(ex<=y for ex in x[3:9]):
     # There is an item that is less than or equal to y in that slice
```

Use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```
 if all(ex>y for ex in x[3:9]):
      # all x[3:9] are > y
```

Those functions will not tell you which item is greater than x[idx] -- only that there exists a condition that is true.

Or if you want the know the index of the first offending item, use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator:

```
x_gr_y_idx=next(i for i in range(3,9) if x[i]>y)
```

And for all the items in a range that are offending:

```
[(i, x[i]) for i in range(3,9) if x[i]>y]
```

Using a slice will silently fail (in this scenario) for a slice that is out of range of the list:

```
>>> li=[1,2,3]
>>> [x<6 for x in li[10:14]]
[]
```

Whereas an index will give an IndexError for a bad index:

```
>>> [li[i]<6 for i in range(10,14)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
IndexError: list index out of range
```